# Matlab d-dimensional multipication table?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and I'm trying to solve a problem that involves creating a d dimensional multiplication table where each edge goes from 1 to n. The problem statement says that inputting d = 0 should return the number 1 and d = 1 should return a column vector with the elements 1 to n.

Ideally, I would just create a matrix of 1 to n along d dimensions and then iterate through for each element setting it equal to the product of the indices, but I don't know how to create the d dimensional matrix.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the table with repeated use of `bsxfun`. At each iteration, the vector 1,2,...,n is shifted to a new dimension and multiplied (with singleton expansion) by the previous result.

```
%// Data
d = 3;
n = 10;

%// Computations
vector = (1:n).'; %// first dimension: column vector
result = 1; %// initialization
for n = 1:d
   result = bsxfun(@times, result, vector); %// new dimension
   vector = shiftdim(vector,-1); %// shift to the next dimension
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't familiar with the shiftdim command.